# How to update rows within time windows of selected times

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm using Postgresql, version "PostgreSQL 10.15, compiled by Visual C++ build 1800, 64-bit". I am working on data which is dumped from a video game, Forza 7. The data includes lots of car data, and a timestamp field called 'wall_clock'. When I crash in game, I signal this by hitting the handbrake - this marks places where I crash, which is otherwise not indicated easily by the data.

I want to mark all data points which are within 5 seconds of a handbrake activation event, before or after the handbrake was used. Or, the same window either side of any row where gear = 0, which indicates I was in reverse, which only happens after a crash. The field I use to mark this is a boolean called 'is_dirty'.

I need a UDF, I think. I've tried implementing a solution in python but it's extremely inefficient. Here is a query which will pull all the rows I am interested in marking;

```
select distinct wall_clock
from raw_data
where 1 = 1

and handbrake > 0
or gear = 0
```

Essentially I need a 'for' loop in SQL which will update any row (set is_dirty = True) in the table raw_data with a wall_clock value that's within 5 seconds of either handbrake being activated (>0) or the gear is Reverse (gear=0).

I've looked at lots of similar questions, but the UDFs usually are too tailored to their data and I can't modify them to work with my table.

Edit: My mistake, thanks to  Adrian Klaver - my Postgresql version is:
"PostgreSQL 10.15, compiled by Visual C++ build 1800, 64-bit"

Comment: There is no Postgres 4.28 version, please update your question with correct version. In `psql` do `select version();`.

Comment: "PostgreSQL 10.15, compiled by Visual C++ build 1800, 64-bit", post edited, thanks for spotting that

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.  What does "mark" mean?

Comment: By 'mark' I mean to set is_dirty to 'True'

Answer (score 0):

> I want to mark all data points which are within 5 seconds of a handbrake activation event, before or after the handbrake was used.

A simple method use window functions, something like this:

```
select r.*,
       (count(*) filter (where handbrake > 0) over 
            (partition by car_id
             order by wall_clock
             range between interval '5 second' preceding and '5 second' following
            ) > 0
       ) as with_5_seconds_of_handbrake
from raw_data r;
```

I can only guess what your column names are and whether you want this *per car* or overall.  But this gives you the key idea.

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=a2fecfdceac215a4e898e92831821f49) is a db<>fiddle. showing that this syntax works in Postgres.

Comment: Thank you! I get an error running the above though:

`ERROR:  RANGE PRECEDING is only supported with UNBOUNDED
LINE 5:              range between interval '5 second' preceding and...
                     ^
SQL state: 0A000
Character: 144`

Column names:

handbrake (int 0-255)
is_dirty (boolean)
wall_clock (timestamp)

I want to essentially differentiate between all the data points within 5 seconds of a crash, which is signalled by using the handbrake.

Comment: @Jordan . . . Postgres has supported this since version 11.